# magento collection filter (range of entity_id)

Tags: collection

How do i get the collection with entity_id which the range between 1-3000?

```
ob_start();
foreach ($customers as $customer){
    $temp = $customer->load($customer->getId())->getData();
    echo $temp['entity_id']."<BR>";
    flush();
        ob_flush();
}
```

anyone knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('gteq'=>1))
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('lteq'=>3000))
```

Comment: My example:  $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id',  array('gt'=>$lastOrderEx))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id',  array('lteq'=>$lastOrderMagento));

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',
            array(array('from'=>'1','to'=>'3000')               
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

My example:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id',  array('gt'=>$lastOrderEx))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id',  array('lteq'=>$lastOrderMagento));
```